# Upgrade to Laravel 5.4 causing undefined method dispatch() on push to Forge

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I recently updated Laravel app from 5.3 -> 5.4 and got it working fine on local computer.

I pushed the update to bitbucket which then deployed to my web server via Forge, but I keep getting the following error;

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
> php artisan optimize
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::dispatch() in     /home/forge/appname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:56
```

I have tried deleting cache files from `/bootstrap/cache` and `storage/framework/`

and also running `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear`

I also tried uninstalling and re-installing the repo on Forge. It seems that it will do the initial install/deploy ok, but then if I push any updates, it fails with the same error.

Anyone got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Only way I found to resolve was to completely delete the site on Forge and then add it as a new one.